# Is it natural to say "she stuck her head out to see the front" or "she stuck her head over to see the front"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, word-request, phrase-request, phrase-choice

[image]

Say you are carrying a girl behind you on your motorbike. She can only look at your back.

If she wants to clearly look at things that are in front of the motorbike, she has to "**stick her head out / over**".

Another example, these people are standing behind a tree and if they want to see things in front of the tree, they have to "**stick their heads out / over**" as shown in this picture.

[image]

Is it natural to say "**she stuck her head out to see the front**" or "**she stuck her head over to see the front**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The people are looking **round** the tree, not **over** [the top of] it.

The pillion passenger might look **over** the rider's shoulder (if she is tall enough), or **round** him, to see **in front** of the bike. (Someone standing at the side of the road would see **the front** of the bike.)

You could also say that she sticks her head out.

Comment: Nice, what about "**standing behind the tree**"?

Comment: Yes, they are standing behind the tree looking round it, or sticking their heads out.

Comment: But "**I looked around him**" could be confusing. Does that mean "**I looked all positions around him**"?

But I just want to **look in front of him**. In dictionaries, preposition "around" or "round" mean "**on, to or from the other side of somebody/something**", but that is British English or Australian English.

I am not sure American people say that way?

Comment: Oddly, I couldn't find any dictionary definitions for _look (a)round_ giving exactly that meaning - but to prove I'm not making it up, see [this](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/look-round-look-around.1616339/) and [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35769/what-does-peer-around-something-mean)